# How to aim a balistic projectile at a moving target?

Tags: game-physics, projectile

i have:

- the target speed and position
- the gravity
- the firing point
  i need to calculate where i should launch the projectile to hit the target 100% of the time in 3D

i found lots of solutions for when the projectile has a constant speed (mine hasn't)

Comment: A ballistic object moves along a parabola `f(y) = axx + bx + c`. The target, assuming it moves at constant speed and direction, moves along a line `f(y) = mx + d`. There are at most two possible intercepts. The intercept will satisfy  `0 = axx + (b-m)x + c - d` which can be solved using the quadratic formula